# Generally suppress line breaking at hyphens followed by parentheses

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

It's not uncommon for me to typeset documents containing words such as "(semi-)automatic" (meaning "automatic or semi-automatic") or "(half-)hourly" (meaning "every hour or every half-hour").  However, typing such a word as-is in a LaTeX document risks ugly line breaks:

> blah blah blah blah (semi-
> )automatic blah blah blah

I know that I can work around this problem on a case-by-case basis by instead typing the word as `\mbox{(semi-)}automatic`, or by using a macro with this definition.  But it would be nice if I didn't have to remember to do this for every such instance of every such word that might appear in a document.

Is there some code I can put in my preamble that tells LaTeX to never break a line at a hyphen if it is followed by a right parenthesis, but that otherwise preserves normal hyphenation and line-breaking rules?

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you make `-` active so it can look forward, but also breaking a lot of other things. I think the problem has already been discussed on the site.

Comment: Do you use `babel`?

Comment: do you use luatex (or xetex)

Comment: Sure, I often use `babel` and XeLaTeX.  If there's no general solution, I'd accept one that required one or both of those two.